# How to build libx264 64bit library for android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, 64-bit, libx264

I am unable to build libx264 code for android arm-64 bit architecture. 
Below is the command i tried.

```
./configure \
--cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- \
--sysroot="$HOME/NDK/android-ndk-r10d/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/" \
--host=arm-linux \
--enable-pic \
--enable-static \
--disable-cli
```

Please advice.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

you may try below:

```
export PLATFORM=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64
export PREBUILT=$ANDROID_NDK_HOME/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt
export PREFIX=../android-lib/arm64

./configure --cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android- \
--sysroot=$PLATFORM \
--host=aarch64-linux \
--enable-pic \
--enable-static \
--extra-cflags="-fPIE -pie" \
--extra-ldflags="-fPIE -pie" \
--disable-cli \
--disable-asm \
--prefix=$PREFIX
```